# SQL - to find the most complete strings in a column from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Each time a user searches for a text on the website, the search text gets recorded to search_table. The sub-searches are also recorded. They are recorded with an asterisk.

The goal is to find the most complete search texts that the user searched for.

The ideal way would be:

```
        Group the ids = 1,4,6 and obtain id=6
        Group the ids = 2,5,7 and obtain id = 7
        Group the ids = 3 and obtain id = 3
        Group the ids 8, 9 and obtain id = 9
```

SEARCH_TABLE

```
            id user   search_text
            --------------------
            1  user1  data manag*
            2  user1  confer*
            3  user1  incomplete sear*
            4  user1  data managem*
            5  user1  conference c*
            6  user1  data management
            7  user1  conference call
            8 user1  status in*
            9 user1  status information
```

Output should be

```
        user  search_text
        ---------------------
        user1 data management
        user1 conference call
        user1 incomplete sear*
        user1 status information
```

Can you help please?

Comment: So the issue is regardless of what you're doing you must have a dictionary file sitting on the side to determine if it is a real word. Otherwise you're gonna end up with "data managementzzz" because it is larger or more complete. You're gonna need a scripting language or a stored procedure

Comment: @FirebladeDan even if the user searched for "data managementzzz" I think it is fine. It can be done with a normal query then, right?

Comment: Would the search for "data managementzzz" exhibit the same behavior in your application as "data management?" If it does then yeah you can just group how you're saying and pick max, but I doubt this is the behavior. What'll happen is "data mana" will produce the correct result whereas "data managementzzz" will probably match 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should do the work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    SEARCH_TABLE st 
    WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT 1 FROM 
        SEARCH_TABLE st2 
        -- remove asterkis and ad %
        WHERE  st2.search_Text LIKE replace(st.search_text,'*','')||'%'
    )
```

This is filtering all searches that are part of others.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant way, but here's a go at it:

```
   alter table your_table
   add group_id int 

   select [user], left(search_text, 5) as Group_Text, IDENTITY(int, 1,1) as Group_ID
   into #group_id_table
   from your_table
   group by [user], left(search_text, 5)
   order by [user], left(search_text, 5)

   update a
   set a.group_id = b.group_id
   from your_table as a
   join #group_id_table as b
   on left(search_text, 5) = group_text

   select [user], max(search_text), group_id
   from your_table
   group by [user], group_id
   order by [user], group_id
```

This achieved the desired results when I ran it, but of course because you're basing the group_id's off a user specified string length there could be issues there. I hope this does the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. I separated out the completed texts (and their shorter partials), and then found the longest partial for each record. Tested in Oracle as I don't have access to a PostgreSQL right now, but I didn't use anything exotic so it should work.

```
with 
  --Contains all completed searches
  COMPLETE   as (select * from SEARCH_TABLE where SEARCH_TEXT not like '%*'),
  --Contains all searches that are incomplete and dont have a completed match
  INCOMPLETE as (
    select S.* 
    from SEARCH_TABLE S 
    left join COMPLETE C 
      on  S.USR = C.USR
      and C.SEARCH_TEXT like replace(S.SEARCH_TEXT, '*', '%')
    where C.ID is null
  ),
  --chains all incompleted with any matching pattern shorter than it.
  CHAINED_INC as (
    select LONGER.USR, LONGER.ID, LONGER.SEARCH_TEXT, SHORTER.SEARCH_TEXT SEARCH_TEXT_SHORT
    from INCOMPLETE LONGER 
    join INCOMPLETE SHORTER
      on  LONGER.SEARCH_TEXT like replace(SHORTER.SEARCH_TEXT, '*', '%')
      and LONGER.ID <> SHORTER.ID
  )
--if a text is not the shorter text for a different record, that means it's the longest text for that pattern.
select distinct T1.USR, T1.SEARCH_TEXT  
from CHAINED_INC T1 
left join CHAINED_INC T2
  on  T1.USR = T2.USR
  and T1.SEARCH_TEXT = T2.SEARCH_TEXT_SHORT
where T2.SEARCH_TEXT_SHORT is null
--finally, union back to the completed texts.
union all
select USR, SEARCH_TEXT from COMPLETE
;
```

Edit: removed ID from select